# How to access variables values used in Java Script from Qt code using QtWebEngine

Tags: c++, qt

If i have HTML page which have JavaScript variable,

```
<script type="text/javascript">{myVar = 333;}</script>
```

I need to call this variable from within my C++ code using Qt - QtWebEngine class.
some how i couldn't what to write in the lambda expression to call the JS variable
here is the snippet i used

```
QWebEngineView *view = new QWebEngineView();
view->load(QUrl::fromLocalFile("D:/test.html"));
page = view->page();
page->runJavaScript(myVar,[](QVariant myHolder){ ???? });
```

How should i use this method "runJavaScript" to call my JS variable to be valid in my C++ code ?

Answer (score 0):

If you care to read the [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwebenginepage.html#runJavaScript-1) of method:

```
void QWebEnginePage::runJavaScript(const QString & scriptSource, FunctorOrLambda resultCallback)
```

You will find that above method runs JS script provided by you, and not the JS code inside the HTML page.

```
page->runJavaScript(myVar,[](QVariant myHolder){ ???? });
                    ^^^^^
```

Please give some thought about what JS script can solve your rest of your issue and pass that code to `runJavaScript` API.

Answer (score -1):

```
page->runJavaScript("myVar",[](const QVariant &myHolder){qDebug()<< myHolder.toInt(); });
```

if you want to pass the value to the class field outside the lambda,use like this:

`page->runJavaScript("myVar",[this](const QVariant &myHolder){this->yourClassMethod(myhodler); })`;